# Using more than one table with linq datasource on custom control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datasource

I'm probably opening myself up to a world of trouble with this one but here goes.  As part of a project I have to have a method of representing a timetable for university students, showing lectures, times, rooms etc.  I'm not a coding pro so I have found (and ok'd with uni) an opensource control by the name of DayPilot lite `www.daypilot.org`.  I have that installed now and am beginning the arduous task of figuring out what to do with it.  I know I need to bind it to a datasource.  My problem is that to give all the information I have mentioned, I need to pull data from 3 tables.  When I go to set up a LinqDataSource on the aspx page I can only pick tables from one.   I have been searching for ages trying to locate some info.  This is the best I have came across: `http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx`.

However it does not make sense to me.  I can't see where he actually connects more than one table to the datasource on the aspx page, in asp code.  Am I missing something glaringly obvious here.  Is it perhaps a case that I connect it to one table through the linq DS and then write queries to pull the rest of the data I need.  In that case how would the data be shown in the calendar if I only connect to one table.  Here is the asp code for the calendar anyway.

```
 `<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="OrionDataClassesDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
        Select="new (Module, Building_code, Event_type)" TableName="Events">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotCalendar1" runat="server" />`
```

Obviously that is very preliminary.  Plenty of work to do.  If someone could give some (simple) advice it would be great.  Thanks....and before anyone says it, I know I need to get rid of the default names haha.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never used LinqDataSource, or anything on the direction of what you are doing right now. I'm still using the all sql-statement-in-code-behind method. So my idea below might not work.

If I understand correctly your question above, define a view to return result of your join tables, and add the view to your DataContext. In the LinqDataSource control, set the Tablename property to the view.